# This sample code has me define something, but I don't want to just yet?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c-preprocessor

I have some open source code, which includes this:

.h:

```
#define TILE_ROWS    6
#define TILE_COLUMNS 2
#define TILE_COUNT   (TILE_ROWS * TILE_COLUMNS)

@class Tile;

@interface TilesViewController : UIViewController {
@private
    CGRect   tileFrame[TILE_COUNT];
    Tile    *tileForFrame[TILE_COUNT];

}
```

And then throughout the .m, like so:

```
   for (int row = 0; row < TILE_ROWS; ++row) {
        for (int col = 0; col < TILE_COLUMNS; ++col) {
```

and

```
tileFrame[index] = frame;
```

and

```
 tileForFrame[index] = tile;
```

But what i want is to be able to set TILE_ROWS to the outcome of, for example:

```
float rowsNeeded = ceil(rowsNeededA/TILE_COLUMNS);
```

So therefore it would need to be later on, but I think the CGRect and Tile can only be defined there. I need help, I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to turn the defines into instance variable and to allocate the arrays dynamically:

```
@class Tile;

@interface TilesViewController : UIViewController {
@private
    int       tileRows;
    int       tileColumns;
    int       tileCount;
    CGRect*   tileFrame;
    Tile**    tileForFrame;
}

...

tileColumns = 2;
tileRows = (rowsNeededA + tileColumns - 1) / tileColumns;
tileCount = tileColumns * tileRows;
tileFrame = (CGRect*)malloc(tileCount * sizeof(CGRect));
tileForFrame = (Tile**)malloc(tileCount * sizeof(Tile*));
```

The for loop then becomes:

```
for (int row = 0; row < tileCount; ++row) {
    for (int col = 0; col < tileCount; ++col) {
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, really appreciated and sorts a lot of my code out. Another small problem i'm having though is lines such as this: ` if (tileForFrame[i].tileIndex == tileIndex) { return i; }` return a bad access error. How can i change this to work with my new code?

Comment: To help you with your smaller problem, I'd have to see the declaration of the Tile struct, class or whatever it is. Maybe you can access it like a referenced C structure, namely "titleForFrame[i]->tileIndex".